# mongodb: how to just get the count of subsets but no subset retrieving

Tags: mongodb

I just read the document of 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields

So I hide the comments in blog list page, but, I want to show comments count in list page.

So how to do the aggregation of subset but no subset retrieving

Comment: I have the same question and wonder how to use the c# driver to retrieve just a subset of fields: in Jason / mongo shell the following works: `db.things.find( { x : "john" }, { z : 1 } );`but how can one build this query with the c# driver?

Answer (score 1):

Best to maintain a dedicated comments counter variable as part of your blog post document.
Denormalization in this case is much faster and efficient than performing some kind of 
counting.